# div style doesn't work with css

Tags: html, css

I want to show are of div.HTML+CSS, but it doesn't show div border.

```
<body>
    <!-- format 1 -->
    <div  id="test">abc</div>
</body>

// css file
#test {
    width: 30%;
    height: 300px;
    left:30%;
    border: solid;
}
```

Just HTML,it works.Confused.Are the two formats same?

```
<!-- format2 -->
<body>
  <div  id="test" style="width: 30%; height: 300px; left:30%; border: solid">abc</div>
</body>
```

**Added**
Both of them do work.In previous version I set div id="18", and in css use #18.  It's wrong.
 I think this question should be closed.

Comment: Well, did you put your css for format 1 in a style tag in the head? Or in a separate file and include it?

Comment: @deadfishli I've done it. Some styles of elements in the css file work. So I'm really confused.

Comment: Hm. It should be working then. Did you check your path again? Maybe you misspelled something in the filepath? Also, please use a border-width in your border style.

Comment: You should really provide a runnable Stack Snippet then, so we can really reproduce the problem (or not, depending). There is an editor button for it.

Answer (score 0):

It *does* show a border here. Most likely you don't have the stylesheet linked properly to the HTML document.

Another explanation would be that there is another rule further down in the stylesheet that overwrites your border setting with `border: none` for that element.

```css
#test {
    width: 30%;
    height: 300px;
    left:30%;
    border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div  id="test">abc</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it then be best to just flag as "can't reproduce" instead of providing a "it works for me" answer?

Comment: I am showing that it works if it's properly defined (and linked ) as HTML and CSS code in the page

Comment: Maybe add that bit of explanation to the answer then. By the way, I did not give you that downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, it *should* work exactly the same both ways. Here is a little JSFiddle to show that: https://jsfiddle.net/av25ro8w/

```
<body> <!--ignore this; StackOverflow makes code compulsory when you send a JSFiddle link-->
    <div id="test">abc</div>
</body>
```

There must be some other error in your code as it seems the code you have provided us is an example and not the exact code you're working with :)